# Web Worker not working when importing module, even while using worker-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, web-worker, worker-loader

I'm trying to make a web worker to prevent stalling the React main thread.  The worker is supposed to read an image and do various things.

The app was created using `create-react-app`.

Currently I have

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.worker\.js$/,
                use: { loader: 'worker-loader' }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

`WebWorker.js`

```
export default class WebWorker {
    constructor(worker) {
        const code = worker.toString();
        const blob = new Blob(['('+code+')()'], {type: "text/javascript"});
        return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob),  {type: 'module'});
    }
}
```

`readimage.worker.js`

```
import Jimp from "jimp";

export default () => {
    self.addEventListener('message', e => { // eslint-disable-line no-restricted-globals
        if (!e) return;
        console.log('Worker reading pixels for url', e.data);
        let data = {};

        Jimp.read(e.data).then(image => {
            // jimp does stuff
            console.log('Worker Finished processing image');
        })

        postMessage(data);
    })
};
```

And then in my React component `AppContent.js` I have

```
import WebWorker from "./workers/WebWorker";
import readImageWorker from './workers/readimage.worker.js';

export default function AppContent() {
    const readWorker = new ReadImageWorker(readImageWorker);
    readWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
        console.log('returned data', event.data);
        setState(data);
    });

    // callback that is executed onClick from a button component
    const readImageContents = (url) => {
        readWorker.postMessage(url);
        console.log('finished reading pixels');
    };
}
```

But when I run it, I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jimp__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not defined

How can I properly import a module into a web worker?

Comment: import in workers is not widely supported yet - looks like Chrome, Edge, and node right now, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility.  have you tried importScripts?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Importing_scripts_and_libraries

Comment: @JamesSouth I looked at using importScripts, but besides it gives a linting error (which I can set to ignore), where am I supposed to import the module from?  I can't use the relative path in the node_modules folder, nor just `jimp`.  The only way to use importScripts with it is to copy the module to the `public` folder and then use an absolute url (such as `http://localhost:3000/jimp.js`).  Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Maybe worker-plugin https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin instead of worker-loader would help??

Answer (score 1):

You might have a problem with webpack importing your worker in the WebWorker class. Try returning `new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob), import.meta.url));` like [how it's documented](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/#example) in the webpack docs.

Comment: thank you very much. in webpack5 fine well for me.

Comment: You are misquoting the document you linked to and your are using the Worker constructor incorrectly.

From your link:
const worker = new Worker(new URL('./deep-thought.js', import.meta.url));

The document you linked to sends import.meta.url to the URL constructor. You are sending it to the Worker constructor. You are using URL.createObjectURL your link is using new URL.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker

Answer (score 1):

In my next.js typescript project, I use this code and answer in my use case:

- `function in onClick prop on the element at next.js`

```
async () => {
  const testWorker = new Worker(
    new URL("./test.worker.ts", import.meta.url), {
      name: "test",
      type: "module",
    });
  testWorker.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log("data:", event.data, "\n", "event:", event);
  };

  testWorker.postMessage([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]);
}
```

- `test.worker.ts`

```
self.onmessage = function ({ data }) {
  self.postMessage((data as number[]).map((d) => d * 10));
};

export {};
```